# SAS date9 format to python datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a CSV formatted with SAS's `[date9.][1]` output. But `dateutil.parser.parse` doesn't recognise it and nor does `pandas.to_datetime` (also a question, does `to_datetime` use `dateutil.parser`?).

They throw:

```
  File "C:\redacted\dateutil\parser.py", line 559, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format")

ValueError: Unknown string format
```

The format looks like this:

```
0         12FEB1993
1         12FEB1993
...
16        16NOV1972
17        01SEP2001
18        06JUL2000
19        01FEB2014
```

With everything that matters in the second column. Is there any library that can solve this or do I have to roll my own? And if it is the latter, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you pass in the `format` argument to `pandas.to_datetime()`? Something like: `pandas.to_datetime(date_column, format='%d%b%Y')`

If you can get the dates as strings, then any date-parsing function that takes `strptime` formatting should work with the pattern `%d%b%Y`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('12FEB1993', '%d%b%Y')
datetime.datetime(1993, 2, 12, 0, 0)
```

EDIT:

It looks like `pandas.to_datetime()` results in `pandas.Timestamp` objects, which, due to [resolution limits](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations) are limited to ~584 years, or a max year of 2262.

Because you have date-string that extend beyond that, you could read the column in as a string, and then call `apply` to convert the values into `date` objects:

```
import datetime
my_df['date'] = my_df['date_text'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y').date())
```

Comment: We've also got datetimes which span to 9999-12-31 standing in for infinity (I guess a year 10k problem, but whatever). What do you think would be best to deal with that?

Comment: `strptime()` will happily process all dates up to 9999-12-31, so there's nothing special that you need to do to support your date range.

Comment: When I try it with `pd`, it fails

Comment: Hmm, it appears that `11APR2262` is the maximum date that `pandas.to_datetime` will process into a timestamp, rather than just returning the original string.

Comment: Aha: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations
"Since pandas represents timestamps in nanosecond resolution, the time span that can be represented using a 64-bit integer is limited to approximately 584 years:"